# I want to know if I can have two music libraries

Tags: 14.04, banshee

Is there a way that I can have two media players like banshee with their own library,so that I can import new mp3's without affecting the music which is in my music library which is already sorted?

Answer (score 1):

Unless you tell your music players to sort them, they usually will leave the files' structure on the disk alone. So you can have multiple music players sharing the same library folder, or having different library folders, and so on.

Comment: can you tell me how I can have a second banshee player from the one I use to sort my new mp3's

Comment: @user179732 You can tell Banshee to run in a mode that uses the current directory for configuration. I haven't tested it, but you can do something like this: `mkdir -p ~/.banshee-2; cd ~/.banshee-2; banshee --uninstalled` It would be simpler if you use a second music player, like Rhythmbox or Clementine.

Answer (score 0):

Generally music players will store their library information (which is different from the music file's location) under their own settings subdirectory in our HOME folder. Therefore each player will create an own different library, and libraries from different users will be different too.

Some players (e.g. [Guayadeque](https://apps.ubuntu.com/cat/applications/guayadeque) [image: Install guayadeque]) allow to create multiple different libraries.

To avoid updating a library on adding new mp3 files there may be a setting in your player where you can disable auto-updating of the library.